# mysql sql statment stops parsing at one row

Tags: mysql, sql, group-by

I am trying to export my products out of prestashop, and am trying to add a image loop to find the images for products. It stops at one row and puts all the images it finds in that single column.

```
select ps_product.id_product, ps_product.upc, ps_product.price, 
ps_product.weight, ps_product.date_add,
GROUP_CONCAT(DISTINCT(CONCAT('/img/p/',
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ps_image.id_image) >= 5, 
CONCAT(
SUBSTRING(ps_image.id_image, -5, 1),
'/'),
''),
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ps_image.id_image) >= 4, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ps_image.id_image, -4, 1), '/'), ''),
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ps_image.id_image) >= 3, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ps_image.id_image, -3, 1), '/'), ''),
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ps_image.id_image) >= 2, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ps_image.id_image, -2, 1), '/'), ''),
IF(CHAR_LENGTH(ps_image.id_image) >= 1, CONCAT(SUBSTRING(ps_image.id_image, -1, 1), '/'), ''),
ps_image.id_image,
'.jpg')) SEPARATOR ', ') AS 'base_image',
ps_stock_available.quantity, ps_product_lang.description, 
ps_product_lang.name, ps_product_lang.description_short, 
ps_product_lang.link_rewrite, ps_product_lang.meta_title, 
ps_product_lang.meta_description
from ps_product
INNER JOIN ps_product_lang ON ps_product.id_product=ps_product_lang.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_stock_available ON ps_product.id_product=ps_stock_available.id_product
INNER JOIN ps_image ON ps_product.id_product=ps_image.id_product
ORDER BY ps_product.id_product;
```

If I remove the image part it will cycle all the rows from the db, I can't figure out where I am going wrong.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`GROUP_CONCAT()` is an aggregating function. When it appears in a query that doesn't also have a `GROUP BY` clause, its function is to make the query have just one row, concatenating everything in the query.

Try adding this right before your ORDER BY clause.

```
GROUP BY ps_stock_available.quantity, ps_product_lang.description, 
         ps_product_lang.name, ps_product_lang.description_short, 
         ps_product_lang.link_rewrite, ps_product_lang.meta_title, 
         ps_product_lang.meta_description
```

You should then get one line of information for each combination of the values in those columns.

You probably should study `GROUP BY` a little as well.